# How can I prove $5^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem was to prove that $5^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ for all nonnegative integers.

I attempted to prove the claim by induction.

Claim: For all $ n \ge 0 $  $$ 3^{n+1} ~|~ 5^{3^n}+1 $$
Basis case:
$$ 3^{0+1} = 3  ~|~ 6 =  5^{3^0} + 1 ~ ~\checkmark$$ 
Inductive step: Assume $$ 3^{k+1} ~|~ 5^{3^k} + 1 $$
It follows by the definition of divides, $ 5^{3^k } + 1 = 3^{k+1}\cdot m $ for some integer $m$.

Then $$~~~~~ 5^{3^{k+1}} +1
\\   = 5^{3^k \cdot 3 }+1 
\\ = 5^{3 \cdot 3^k}+1  
\\ = \left( 5^3 \right)^{3^k} +1 
\\=  125^{3^k} +1 $$ I have no idea how to proceed. Am I on the right track? If it is possible can I get a hint.
One thing I did notice is that it might be easier to prove $$ 3^{n} ~|~ 5^{3^n}+1 $$ This statement seems to be true, since the basis case is then $1|6$.

Comment: Can you factorise $x^3+1$?

Comment: This question is locked. I was just about to answer it based on the hints :/ It is not a duplicate of another question, though it does bear some similarity. It also looks like other contributors were deleted once the question got locked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @john The same methods in the answers on the linked question work here.In fact both amswers here are dupes of answers there. We have tens if not hundreds of instances of these problems. You can find them by searching at [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fact that $x^3 +1 = (x+1)(x^2 -x+1).$